# HTML Span text toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a span

```
<span id="spanActive">Show Inactive</span>
```

Trying to change the text using JQuery like below:

```
$('#spanActive').text(($(this).text()=='Show Inactive') ? 'Hide Inactive' : 'Show Inactive');
```

but not working.

Comment: Are you sure that `this` is `#spanActive` element?

Comment: Add $ in ('#spanActive').text(($(this).text()=='Show Inactive') ? 'Hide Inactive' : 'Show Inactive');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code

```
$('#spanActive').text(($('#spanActive').text()=='Show Inactive') ? 'Hide Inactive' : 'Show Inactive');
```

You need to use `this` in event handler which will be having current object in "`this`".

Check working demo at this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/XZfAK/1/)

If you are using `this` in click event handler for span, try with below code

```
$('#spanActive').click(function () {
    if($(this).text() == 'Show Inactive')
         $(this).text('Hide Inactive');
    else
        $(this).text( 'Show Inactive');
});
```

Check demo at this link[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/XZfAK/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Why will it work if this code is not encased inside a event handler, as `this` has no context outside it.

```
('#spanActive').on('click', function() {
     $(this).text(($(this).text()=='Show Inactive') 
                  ? 'Hide Inactive' : 'Show Inactive');
});
```

If you want to use it outside the context of the event then you can try this

```
('#spanActive').text(function(_, txt) {
         return txt === 'Show Inactive'? 'Hide Inactive' : 'Show Inactive'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#spanActive').text(($('#spanActive').text()=='Show Inactive') ? 'Hide Inactive' : 'Show Inactive');
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/w2gFW/)

> Your code have a 'this' reference which is refering document, not the span. So use :

```
  $('#spanActive').text(($("#spanActive").text() == 'Show Inactive') ? 'Hide Inactive' : 'Show Inactive');
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` doesn't works in this context.. Try this:

```
$('#spanActive').text(($("#spanActive").text() == 'Show Inactive') ? 'Hide Inactive' : 'Show Inactive');
```